# How to get the size of a Node.js writable stream (HTTP server response)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, logging

I would like to write an express middleware printing HTTP access log in the Common (Access) Log format. The last column in this format is the size of the response body in bytes.

How to determine a size of the HTTP response produced by the Node.js server?

Example that does not work:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var bytes = 0;
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    bytes += chunk.length;
  });
  res.on('finish', function() {
    // `bytes` is the response size
    console.log(/* common log entry */);
  });
});
```

I have done some research, for example Hapi's [common-log](https://github.com/rockbot/hapi-common-log/blob/bc5c2d03737ad6fb690a4735569f850e410e070d/index.js#L17) always emits `-` as the size. Does it mean it is not possible to obtain the size?

Comment: Why it does not work?

Comment: Because `data` is emitted by readable streams, not by writable streams.

Comment: If nothing else, there's always monkey-patching `res.write` if response length is that important to you.

Comment: @mscdex Yes, that's an option. Together with `Buffer.byteLength(data, encoding)`, which supposedly implies a significant performance penalty.

Comment: You'd only need to call that method for strings passed to `write()`. Buffers have their own `.length` property.

Answer (score -4):

Try this code:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var data = [];
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        data.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on('finish', function() {
        console.log( Buffer.concat(data).toString().length() );
    });
});
```

Comment: Note the comment under my question: "data" is emitted by readable streams, not by writable streams.

Comment: The response implements the Writable Stream interface.
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v5.x/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse

Comment: var req = http.request(options, function(responseStream){
  responseStream.on('data', function(chunk){
    /**/
  });
});